# Kubernetes GKE - how to route traffic through a specific gateway

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to configure static routes to route traffic to specific external IP through a specific gateway (with static public IP address) on Google Kubernetes?

Our software runs on Google Kubernetes and from time to time has to connect to  external system which does IP white listing.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, let's see. :-) An API gateway is a service in kubernetes like anyone else, but it has an ingress. The ingress provides the static public IP number to the service. Then you need some code running three to make the actual routing to the correct service inside your kubernetes network. Depending on what protocols you need to support, you have different options. In Java Spring Cloude Gateway or the predecessor zuul (http only) are two popular options. Read up on those and see if to find your answer there, else come back with more details!

Comment: Thanks but I am about egress case. Unfortunately this is not supported on Kubernetes so had to do it via NAT instance and extra route.